# reprint receipt with the order date Odoo 14 community version

Tags: odoo, point-of-sale, receipt

thanks in advance, kindly check my first comment
**when i reprint the receipt **the output came with the current date and time
i need the order actual date and time
this is the code

if i leave just

it does not show the date when reprinting

so i add this

and it print the current date not the order date when reprinting the order

this is the entire code

```
<t t-name="OrderReceipt" t-inherit="point_of_sale.OrderReceipt" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
     <!--Override-->
     <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('pos-receipt-contact')]" position="replace" >
         <div class="pos-receipt-contact">
                <t t-if="receipt.company.contact_address">
                    <div><t t-esc="receipt.company.contact_address" /></div>
                </t>
                 <t t-if="receipt.company_address">
                    <div><t t-esc="receipt.company_address"/></div>
                </t>
                <t t-if="receipt.company_state">
                    <div><t t-esc="receipt.company_state"/></div>
                    <div>----------------------------------</div>
                </t>
                <t t-if="receipt.company.phone">
                    <div>Tel:<t t-esc="receipt.company.phone" /></div>
                </t>

                <t t-if="receipt.company.email">
                    <div><t t-esc="receipt.company.email" /></div>
                </t>
                <t t-if="receipt.company.website">
                    <div><t t-esc="receipt.company.website" /></div>
                </t>
                <t t-if="receipt.header_html">
                    <t t-raw="receipt.header_html" />
                </t>
                <t t-if="!receipt.header_html and receipt.header">
                    <div style="white-space:pre-line"><t t-esc="receipt.header" /></div>
                </t>
                <t t-if="receipt.cashier">
                    <div class="cashier">
                        <div>--------------------------------</div>
                        <div>Served by <t t-esc="receipt.cashier" /></div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </div>
     </xpath>
     <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('pos-receipt-order-data')]" position="replace">
          <div class="pos-receipt-order-data">
          </div>
     </xpath>

    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('orderlines')]" position="before">
         <div style='text-align:center;border-bottom: 2px solid black;margin-bottom:3px'>
            <div><strong> فاتورة ضريبية مبسطة </strong></div>
            <div> <strong> SIMPLIFIED TAX INVOICE </strong></div>
        </div>
         <table class='receipt-orderlines'>
                <colgroup>
                    <col width='35%' />
                    <col width='65%' />
                </colgroup>
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6">
                    <td style='text-align:left'>Invoice No:<br/> رقم الفاتورة </td>
                     <td>
                        <span t-esc="receipt.name"/>
                    </td>

                </tr>

              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6">
                    <td>Issue Date: <br/>  تاريخ الإصدار </td>
                    <td>
                        <span t-if="!receipt.date.localestring" t-esc="receipt.date.isostring"/>
                        <span t-if="receipt.date.localestring" t-esc="receipt.date.localestring"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
               <tr t-if="receipt.company.vat" style="border-bottom: 0px solid #cccccc;">
                    <td>VAT No: <br/>الرقم الضريبي </td>
                    <td>
                        <t t-esc="receipt.company.vat" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        <br/>

    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('orderlines')]" position="replace">
        <div class="orderlines">
            <table class='receipt-orderlines' style="border-bottom:1px solid #000">
                <colgroup>
                    <col width='30%' />
                    <col width='15%' />
                    <col width='20%' />
                    <col width='30%' />
                </colgroup>
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;border-top: 1px solid black;">
                    <th style='text-align:left'>Item <br/> الصنف </th>
                    <th style='text-align:center'>Qty <br/> الكمية</th>
                    <th style='text-align:center'>Unit Price <br/> سعر الوحدة</th>
                    <th style='text-align:center'>Subtotal<br/>السعر بالضريبة </th>
                </tr>
                <tr t-foreach="orderlines" t-as="orderline" t-key="orderline.id">
                    <td>
                        <t t-esc="orderline.get_product().display_name"/>
                         <t t-if="orderline.get_discount() > 0">
                            <div class="pos-disc-font">
                                With a <t t-esc="orderline.get_discount()"/>% discount
                            </div>
                        </t>
                    </td>
                    <td style='text-align:center'>
                        <t t-esc="orderline.get_quantity()"/>
```

-->

```
                    </td>
                    <td style='text-align:center'>
                        <t t-esc="env.pos.format_currency_no_symbol(orderline.get_unit_display_price())"></t>
                    </td >
                    <td style='text-align:right'>
                        <t t-esc="env.pos.format_currency_no_symbol(orderline.get_price_with_tax())"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//t[@t-if='!isTaxIncluded']" position="replace">
        <div class="pos-receipt-right-align">--------</div>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <div class="pos-receipt-left-align" style="float:left;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <div>Total Taxable (Excluding VAT)</div>
                <div> الاجمالي الخاضع للضريبة</div>
            </div>
            <span t-esc="env.pos.format_currency(receipt.subtotal)" class="pos-receipt-right-align" style="margin-top:5px"/>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <t t-foreach="receipt.tax_details" t-as="tax" t-key="tax.name">
            <div style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
                 <div class="pos-receipt-left-align" style="float:left">
                    <div>Total VAT</div>
                    <div> مجموع ضريبة القيمة المضافة</div>
                 </div>
                <div class="pos-receipt-right-align" style="margin-top:5px">
                    <span t-esc='env.pos.format_currency(tax.amount)' />
                </div>

                <br/>
            </div>
        </t>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('pos-receipt-amount')]" position="replace">
        <div class="pos-receipt-amount" style="padding:0px;">
          <div class="pos-receipt-left-align" style="float:left;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <div>Total Amount</div>
                <div>إجمالي المبلغ المستحق</div>
          </div>
            <span t-esc="env.pos.format_currency(receipt.total_with_tax)" class="pos-receipt-right-align" style="margin-top:10px"/>
            <br/>
        </div>

    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//t[@t-foreach='receipt.paymentlines']" position="replace">
        <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <t t-foreach="receipt.paymentlines" t-as="line" t-key="line.cid">
                <div>
                     <div class="pos-receipt-left-align" style="margin-bottom: 5px;width:80%; display:inline-block">
                    <div><t t-esc="line.name" /> </div>
                    <div>المدفوع</div>
                 </div>
                  <span t-esc="env.pos.format_currency_no_symbol(line.amount)" class="pos-receipt-right-align" style="margin-top:10px; width:20%;" />
                <br/>
            </div>
        </t>
        </div>
 </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('pos-receipt-amount') and hasclass('receipt-change')]" position="replace">
    <div class="pos-receipt-amount receipt-change" style="padding:0px;">
         <div class="pos-receipt-left-align" style="margin-bottom: 10px; width:80%; display:inline-block">
                <div>CHANGE</div>
                <div>المتبقي</div>
          </div>
             <span t-esc="env.pos.format_currency(receipt.change)" class="pos-receipt-right-align" style="margin-top:10px; width:20%;"/>
     </div>
 </xpath>

    <xpath expr="//div[@class='pos-receipt-order-data']" position="before">
        <div>
            <div style="margin:10px; text-align: center; padding:0 13%;">
                <span id="qr_data" t-esc="receipt.qr_code" style="display: NONE;"/>
                <div id="qrcode" style="width:100%; height:200px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align: center;"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var  qrData = document.getElementById("qr_data").innerHTML;
                    new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {"text": qrData ,width:200, height:200, correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H});
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</t>
```

Comment: date and time
this is the code

<span t-if="!receipt.date.localestring" t-esc="receipt.date.isostring"/>
<span t-if="receipt.date.localestring" t-esc="receipt.date.localestring"/>



if i leave just 
<span t-if="receipt.date.localestring" t-esc="receipt.date.localestring"/>
 it does not show the date when reprinting

so i add this 
*<span t-if="!receipt.date.localestring" t-esc="receipt.date.isostring"/>*
and it print the current date not the order date when reprinting the order